# How can I make `git submodules update` checkout the branch specified in .gitmodules rather than that branch's latest commit?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Each submodule in my `project`'s `.gitmodules` has `branch` set to either `origin/master` or `origin/main`, but `git submodule update` always checks out the latest commit in `main` rather than the branch itself. Because the branch is not checked out, and there are of course no changes made to an existing commit, VS Code does not know to check for new commits in the branch that should be synced before new changes are made locally. This can cause issues when editing the project on multiple devices.

How can I make `git submodule update` checkout the branch specified in `.gitmodules` rather than the latest commit in that branch? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of specifying `branch` in `.gitmodules`, or the reason for checking out the commit rather than the specified branch?

Comment: Yes, you misunderstand. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797720/7976758 found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+branch : "*The submodule object is still pointing at a specific commit. The only thing that the `-b` option buys you is the ability to add a `--remote` flag to your update*" See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt--bltbranchgt): "*for update --remote*"